# Can't get server access permissions working

Tags: permissions

I am trying to get a script going that will move files in the apache webserver directory for me without sudo. In my mucking around I somehow got edit and move permissions working for user `nhergert`, but when I tried to trace my steps again it didn't work with `tom`. Permissions of the file (user `www-data` and group `www-data` are owners, the sticky bit is **not** set, permissions of 770):

```
-rwxrwx---  1 www-data www-data      1766 Jun 23 16:28 index4.html
```

Members in group `www-data`:

```
> getent group www-data
www-data:x:33:nhergert,tom
```

`tom` and `nhergert` are both members of `www-data`:

```
> id nhergert
uid=1000(nhergert) gid=1000(nhergert) groups=1000(nhergert),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),33(www-data),46(plugdev),109(lpadmin),124(sambashare)
> id tom
uid=1001(tom) gid=1001(tom) groups=1001(tom),33(www-data),1000(nhergert)
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry everyone! Apparently changes to groups don't update until the next time the user logs in. So, `tom`'s membership in `www-data` applied when I closed his terminal session and logged back in.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess it's a problem of the directory (where `index4.html` is located) not having the correct access bits.  Not only the files, but also all parent directories need to have `rwx` access (or whatever you need) for the `www-data` group too.

Comment: Good idea. I thought it was that except `nhergert` has access too.